# Notification.Builder and FLAG_INSISTENT

Tags: android

I like the ease of use of `Notification.Builder` but it seems not support the insistent mode of notifications.

Is there a way to set the flag `FLAG_INSISTENT` from the `Notification.Builder`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not directly. There is a private `setFlag()` method on `Notification.Builder` -- I do not know why they did not expose it.

However, you can configure the rest of the `Notification` via a `Builder`, then adjust the flags on the completed `Notification` object.

Or, grab the code for `Notification.Builder` and modify it to create your own that exposes `setFlag()`, or adds `setInsistent()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, adjusting the flags on the completed Notification object is the workaround I'm using. I was wondering if there was a way to set the flag from the Notification.Builder but, apparently, it seems not.

Comment: FLAG_INSISTENT is not working in Oreo above.can you please suggest something?

Comment: @PoojaShukla: If there is anything like `FLAG_INSISTENT`, it likely would be part of the notification channel, as that is where sounds are configured. However, I do not know of an option that would work like `FLAG_INSISTENT` used to. But, I have not researched the point much.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe my answer can be useful to someone else

You can use:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext());

builder.setContentTitle("Title")
       .setContentText("Hello world")
       .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

Notification notification = builder.build();
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(ID, notification)
```