# Set notification in loop until user click

Tags: android, push-notification, fcmp

here is my code of notification:

```
   private void APP_FOREGROUND_showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent) {
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    String channelId = "CHANNEL_ID";
    String channelName = "CHANNEL NAME";

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();



        mChannel.setDescription(title);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.offic), attributes); // Here you set the sound


        if (manager != null)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
     }
     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.vb_grey)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.offic))
            .setContentText(message).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;

    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

This is my notification code.

I have used .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT) for looping but notification sound coming one time only.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the flag by using `setDefaults()`

You can use the following code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.vb_grey)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setOngoing(true)  //<-- you also need this one
            .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.offic))
            .setContentText(message).setAutoCancel(true).setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

Notification notification = builder.build();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
```

also check [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033380/notification-builder-and-flag-insistent)

Comment: by using this ,notification ring  only one time

Comment: i have updated the post and run FLAG_INSISTENT like above but its run single times only.

Comment: Sorry, did you also try with `|=` instead of `=`, because the assignment I had written might have overwritten other flags.

Comment: @HarishRawal you actually also need to set the Ongoing option in the builder with `.setOngoing(true)`. I have updated my answer

Comment: same result ringing one time.